# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException when handling multiple windows using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click multiple links from a website which opens in a new tab.
Switch from parent window to first child window works and back to parent window works perfectly fine.
Switch from parent window to second child window is giving - Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

**Code**

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");

    By linkedln = By.xpath("//img[@alt='LinkedIn OrangeHRM group']");
    By facebook = By.xpath("//img[@alt='OrangeHRM on Facebook']");


    driver.findElement(linkedln).click();
    Set<String> allwindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = allwindows.iterator();

    String parent_window = it.next();
    String child_window1 = it.next();

    driver.switchTo().window(child_window1);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("child window1 title is " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();

    driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);

    driver.findElement(facebook).click();
    
    String child_window2 = it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(child_window2);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("child window1 title is " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();

    driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);

    driver.quit();
```

**Exception**

child window1 title is Sign Up | LinkedIn
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:760)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:780)
at com.basics.Chapter3.HandleMutipleWindows.main(HandleMutipleWindows.java:41)

Answer (score 0):

After come back to parent window, you need initialize all window again.

Check it out:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");

By linkedln = By.xpath("//img[@alt='LinkedIn OrangeHRM group']");
By facebook = By.xpath("//img[@alt='OrangeHRM on Facebook']");


driver.findElement(linkedln).click();
Set<String> allwindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it = allwindows.iterator();

String parent_window = it.next();
String child_window1 = it.next();

driver.switchTo().window(child_window1);
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("child window1 title is " + driver.getTitle());
driver.close();

driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);

driver.findElement(facebook).click();

//here
allwindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
it = allwindows.iterator();
parent_window = it.next();

String child_window2 = it.next();
driver.switchTo().window(child_window2);
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("child window1 title is " + driver.getTitle());
driver.close();

driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);
```